# Получение объекта эдемента управления по его ID

Tags: mfc, c++

Доброго времени суток. Как получить объект класса элемента управления диалогового окна, созданного через редактор, по его ID? В частности есть на диалоговом окне CListCtrl с IDC_LIST_CLIENTS. Мне надо получить этот объект у добавить в него столбцы. Как добавить я знаю. Я не знаю как добраться до этого объекта зная окно располажения и его id((

П.С. Вариант с Wizard мне не нравится, ибо не очень умею им пользоваться, а времени разбираться нет.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Уж незнаю помжет ли это, так как mfc игнорирую по своим, одному мне ведомым причинам, но на winapi можно так:

```
HWND hListOfUnit=GetDlgItem(hWnd, n);
```

Где:

- `hWnd` – Родитель
- `n` - Номер id объекта

Answer (score -1):

Ну это несложно сделать, зная родительское окно данного объекта класса "CListCtrl".
А родительское окно, если это Forms-приложение, можно получить так, если я не ошибаюсь:

```
HINSTANCE hinst = hInstance; // главное окно приложения
```

Теперь получаем дочернее окно с классом `CListCtrl`:

```
HWND h = FindWindowEx(hinst,0,"CListCtrl",NULL); // теперь можно манипулировать 
                                                    дочерним окном, как угодно( h ).
```